# Genexus SECURITY API y firmar un texto

Tags: genexus

Necesito firmar un texto y previendo que las funciones de Genexus van a quedar obsoletas cuando cambie mi versión tengo que moverme a GENEXUS SECURITY API.

Lo que tengo que hacer basicamente es lo que esta en la wiki:

```
&errorCode = &CryptoCert.Load("my_keystore.pfx", &pwd)
if &errorCode = 0
    if (&CryptoCert.HasPrivateKey())
          &CryptoSign.Algorithm = CryptoSignAlgorithm.SHA1withRSA
          &CryptoSign.Certificate = &CryptoCert
          &signedText = &CryptoSign.Sign(&textToSign, false)
          if &CryptoSign.ErrCode <> 0
             //Process Errors
          endif
     else
         //Process Errors
     endif
else
    //Process Errors
endif
```

Lo anterior ya no será valido a partir del upgrade 5 de Gx18. Ahora al querer usar la api no estoy encontrando en la API como firmar un texto o sea, como hacer lo que hace la linea

```
&signedText = &CryptoSign.Sign(&textToSign, false)
```

Alguna idea?
Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finalmente me estaba faltando importar el modulo de criptografia.
Lo resolví con:

```
AsymmetricSigner.DoSign(privateKey, hashAlgorithm, plainText)
```

Esta bien explicado en el link:
[Asymmetric Signing](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?42687,Asymmetric%20Signing)